# Accessing nested forms data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, simple-form

I'm trying to build an app for online single page quizzes, so i'm using nested forms. My problem comes when i try to access data from nested classes, I'm confused on how to handle this as a best practice.

The app has a Quiz class, which has Questions, and each question has multiple Alternatives.

quizzes_controller.rb :

```
def take
    @quiz = Quiz.find(params[:id])
    @user_quiz = @quiz
    #SAVE ANSWERS TO CURRENT USER
end
```

---

take.html.erb :

```
<%= simple_form_for @user_quiz do |quiz| %>
    <%= quiz.simple_fields_for :questions do |question| %>
    **<!-- this should show question.statement -->**
        <div class="custom-controls-stacked">
            <%= question.input :answer, collection: **#this should be question.alternatives**
            ,as: :radio_buttons, class:"custom-control-input" %>
        </div>
    <% end %>

<%= quiz.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

---

quiz.rb :

```
class Quiz < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :session
  has_many :questions
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions
end
```

---

question.rb

```
class Question < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :quiz
  has_many :alternatives
end
```

---

alternative.rb

```
class Alternative < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :question
end
```

---

schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20171008213618) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "alternatives", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text "answer"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "question_id"
    t.index ["question_id"], name: "index_alternatives_on_question_id"
  end


  create_table "questions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text "statement"
    t.integer "correct_answer"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "quiz_id"
    t.integer "answer", default: 0
    t.index ["quiz_id"], name: "index_questions_on_quiz_id"
  end

  create_table "quizzes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "minutes", default: 20
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "session_id"
    t.index ["session_id"], name: "index_quizzes_on_session_id"
  end


end
```

How can I access said data (question.statement is a string, and question has_many alternatives), when questions is a nested class?

Comment: paste your question model, alternative modal  and thier attributes as well

Comment: Updated it, thanks for the interest!